# How to redirect to home page right after successful Authorization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

In order to access Home Page after successful Logging In, user needs to refresh the whole page (otherwise he will not be redirected to home page automatically). What is the possible problem and how to solve it? Here are my source codes:

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
       <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact component={ MainPage }></Route>
            <Route path='/login' component={ LogIn }></Route>
            <Route component={ NotFoundPage }></Route>
       </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

LogIn.js

```
const userIdRegex = RegExp(
  /^[uU]*1+[0-9]*$/
);

class LogIn extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userId: null,
      password: null,
      fullName: undefined,
      responseError: false,
      loggedIn: false,
      formErrors: {
        userId: "",
        password: ""
      }
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let formErrors = { ...this.state.formErrors };

    switch (name){

      case "userId":
        formErrors.userId = userIdRegex.test(value)
          ? ""
          : "Invalid user ID";
        break;
      case "password":
        formErrors.password =
          value.length < 8 ? "Invalid password" : "";
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    this.setState({ formErrors, [name]: value }, () => console.log(this.state));
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      axios.post('url', { userId: e.target.elements.userId.value,
      password: e.target.elements.password.value })
        .then((response) => {
          if(response.status=200){
            this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
            let responseJSON = response;
            sessionStorage.setItem("userData", responseJSON);
          } else {
            console.log("Log In Error");
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.setState({ responseError: true });
        });

  };

  render() {
    if ( this.state.loggedIn ) {
      return (<Redirect to={'/'} />);
    }
    if ( sessionStorage.getItem('userData') ){
      return (<Redirect to={'/'} />);
    }
    const { formErrors } = this.state;
    const responseError = this.state.responseError;
    // const loggedIn = this.state.loggedIn;
    // const { from } = this.props.location.state || '/';

    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="form-wrapper">
        <img src={Logo} className="App-logo" alt="Logo" />
        <p>To Log In enter your user ID and password.</p>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>      
            <div className="userId">
              <input
                autoFocus
                className={formErrors.userId.length > 0 ? "error" : null}
                placeholder="User ID"
                type="text"
                name="userId"
                noValidate
                defaultValue="u"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              {formErrors.userId.length > 0 && (
                <span className="errorMessage">{formErrors.userId}</span>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="password">
              <input
                className={formErrors.password.length > 0 ? "error" : null}
                placeholder="Password"
                type="password"
                name="password"
                noValidate
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              {formErrors.password.length > 0 && (
                <span className="errorMessage">{formErrors.password}</span>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="createAccount">
              <button type="submit" disabled={!this.state.userId} disabled={!this.state.password}>
                Log in
            </button>
            </div>
          </form>
          { responseError==true && (
            <span className="response-error errorMessage">Please enter valid user values</span>
          ) }
        </div>
        </div>
      )}
  }

export default LogIn;
```

MainPage.js

```
class MainPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          redirect: false,
        }
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
        this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
          if( sessionStorage.getItem('userData') ){
              console.log('User Logged In');
          } else {
            this.setState({redirect: true})
          }
      }

    logout(){
        sessionStorage.setItem('userData', '');
        sessionStorage.clear();
        this.setState({redirect: true})
    }
    render(){
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return (<Redirect to={'/login'} />);
        }
        return(
        <div>
            <p>Welcome</p>
            <button onClick={this.logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>

        );
    }
}
export default MainPage;
```

When I remove componentDidMount() method from MainPage.js it solves the problem with redirect, but Main Page becomes accessible without logging in by URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All route components have access to the `history` object in the props, so you could do `this.props.history.push('/')` after successful login in the `LogIn` component.

```
class LogIn extends Component {
  // ...

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("url", {
        userId: e.target.elements.userId.value,
        password: e.target.elements.password.value
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
          sessionStorage.setItem("userData", response);
          this.props.history.push("/");
        } else {
          console.log("Log In Error");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ responseError: true });
      });
  };

  // ...
}
```